# Why might this link not be working...?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm rendering a bunch of posts on a page where a user can browse listings and click on one of them and be sent to a 'singles page' for more information on whatever product they clicked. This method works for every link EXCEPT for the first one.

Anytime I click on the very first link of the page, I get a **Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.** error.

The logic I have in place for the HMTL/jinja is (everything is closed off properly, I'm cutting some unnecessary code for the sake of brevity):

```
{% set i = 0 %}
   {% for row in data %}
      {% set i = i + 1 %}

                       <a href="/iLike/{{ i }}">
                                <li>content</li>
                       </a>
```

and my python code:

```
@app.route('/iLike/<int:num>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def single2(num):
  try:
    loc = session.get('loc')
    transType = session.get('transType')
    data = singlesQuery()


    return render_template('single.html', loc=loc,transType=transType,data=data[num-1])
except Exception as e:
    return (str(e))
```

Comment: There is already `loop.index` in jinja2, you don't need to `set i`.

Comment: What does the URL show when you hover over the link?

Comment: using local host and then the url shows /iLike/1/ @Soviut

Comment: It looks like `/iLike/1/` has an extra slash at the end. Is the one which works `/iLike/2`?

Comment: You're doing `data[num-1]` Why not simply send the `0` through on the URL? `loop.index` would do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to build URLs manually. The best way it to use flask's built-in function [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.url_for):

```
{{url_for('single2', num=i)}}
```

There is also no need for calculating the `i` manually, becaue there is built-in `loop.index` and `loop.index0`:

```
{% for row in data %}
    <a href="{{url_for('single2', num=loop.index)}}">
```

I believe this should always create a valid URL.

Comment: Still getting the error on the very first link. hmm. @zvone I switched to the second suggestion..

Comment: @user3344239 I suggested the trailing slash in comments ;) anyway, do you still have the trailing slash with this code here?

Comment: I didn't suggest trailing slash. This is the correct answer. You should be using `url_for()` since it will properly format your URLs without a trailing slash.

Comment: I wanted to allow the trailing slash, so I added it into the @app.route. I also reformatted the code using your suggestions. Thank you both.